# Cannot see my wordpress website on google search

Tags: wordpress, seo, search-engine

Hi guys I recently uploaded a site made with wordpress.
The site url is [oakabeachvolley.gr](http://www.oakabeachvolley.gr)

I have set on the privacy settings of wordpress for the site to be visible by search engines.  However after almost 45 days the site is invisible on google even when I'm searching using the url name and very specific keywords.

Since I have made quite a few sites with wordpress I have never seen this behavior before. Sites will eventually be visible to google engine, sometimes even in the first day.
However in this case the site does not show nowhere in the first 20 pages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just tried searching 'oaka beach volley' and your site was the top result.

Comment: hehe I feel so embarrassed. A few hours ago nothing would show up and now it is working... :) Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create two files `robots.txt` and `sitemap.xml` and upload on your site and then google crawler will come to your site. You can use **[Google Webmaster Tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en)** for that.

Also, there are some wordpress plugins available to create sitemaps for example. See this:

http://www.arnebrachhold.de/projects/wordpress-plugins/google-xml-sitemaps-generator/